# Segue to new view when UITextField within Custom TableView Cell tapped

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextField within a Custom UITableViewCell.

I need to segue to a new view controller when the UITextField that sits within the custom cell, is tapped.

**Attempted Solutions**

I tried performing the segue inside the CustomTableViewCell class using

```
public func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("Text Field Tapped")
    return false 
}
```

however this didn't work becuase performSegue is a ViewController function. Then I tried

```
func someAction() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: self) 
}
```

in MyViewController class, however that also did not work (not sure why). This is what my two classes look like:

**MyViewController (holds UITableView)**

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:SearchTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! SearchTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

**CustomTableViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var someTextField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.someTextField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Any help that you smart people can provide is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TFCell", for: indexPath) as! TFCell
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension TableViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "TFSegue", sender: textField)
        return false
    }
}

class TFCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
}
```

"TFSegue" is a segue from "TableViewController" to the targetviewcontroller created in storyboard. feel free to ask if anything is unclear!

Comment: Really appreciate the help! Thanks. Not sure if you have any experience with Custom SearchBars in Swift, but if you do could you take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641521/swift-custom-searchcontroller-and-searchbar ? Thanks again!